# Putting array in $_SESSION variable triggers Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

hello guys i am trying to put an array in $_SESSION[] variable, but when i try to run the code it triggers this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

here is my code

```
$stmt1=$conn->prepare('SELECT st_id FROM stores WHERE user_id= :user_id');
 $stmt1->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt1->execute();
$numofst=$stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($numofst as $row){
$_SESSION['st_id']= $row;
}
echo $_SESSION['st_id'][1];
```

i tried to change the position of the number that points the column for example
echo $_SESSION[1]['st_id']; but i get  the same error

when i put the rows in normal array for example :

```
 $stmt1=$conn->prepare('SELECT st_id FROM stores WHERE user_id= :user_id');
  $stmt1->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt1->execute();
$numofst=$stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($numofst as $row){
$stores_number[]= $row;
}
echo $stores_number[1]['st_id'];
```

everything works fine with no issues

what am i missing guys?

thanks in advance

vaggelis

Comment: Set `$_SESSION['st_id']` as an array before the `foreach`. `$_SESSION['st_id'] =array();`

Comment: hey @Kishor I did it but i get the same error :/..any ideas?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION'

Comment: I am sorry, Try `var_dump($_SESSION['st_id']);`

Comment: array(1) { ["st_id"]=> string(2) "40" }, the array should have 3 rows in this queue

Comment: `$_SESSION['st_id'] =array();` before `foreach` and `$_SESSION['st_id'][]=$row` inside the loop.

Comment: this works, thank you very much @kishor. is my question really duplicated as marked by john conde?

Comment: Not really, but kind off, I would say :)